# How to make effective unions that work well together?

Tags: the-last-remnant

What sort of team makeup will perform the best in battle? Should I put fighters and mages together in unions or group them separately? What about healers and the like? What are the considerations when deciding on team composition? What formations benefit different types of unions? Should I have more unions or more numerous unions?

Answer (score 1):

Put mages with mages, and fighters with fighters. Each group should preferably have at least one healer.

The first reason for that is that to improve a units skills, it have to use those skills. So if you put a combination of magic users and fighters in the same group, they will all be "all-rounders". If, on the other hand, you put all magic users in one group, and all fighters in another, they will specialize and learn more powerful skills.

Secondly, if you put all mages together, the commands that are available to choose from are more likely to include the optimal type for that unit. An all-fighter group will almost always have an action that uses the available fighting skills. For a mixed group, about half of the time your units will end up performing a regular attack, which does a lot less damage.